# Difference between $cordovaCamera and navigator.camera

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

While working on an Ionic app , i came across many usages of cordova plugins. like how to take picture from camera or how to pick contacts from phonebook , but i found several examples using two different ways to do it .

For example :

1: using $cordovaCamera ([example](http://sourcefreeze.com/cordova-camera-plugin-example-using-ionic-framework/))

2: navigator.camera ([example](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/working-example-to-upload-photo-from-camera-or-galley-with-ngcordova/12852))

My Question is what exactly is the difference between the two , is it because of the Cordova versions ?

I also see the using navigator.camera does not require ngCordova to be injected in the module whereas using $cordovaCamera requires .

Thansks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about two common usages of Cordova plugins as follows:

### Cordova Only:

This is where you only make use of Cordova plugins without additional libraries and plugins are basically available under navigator object, like (navigator.camera).

Cordova Docs: https://cordova.apache.org/

### Cordova + AngularJS = ngCordova

If you use AngularJS, ngCordova will provide you with simple AngularJS wrappers (i.e $cordovaCamera) for the most popular Cordova and PhoneGap plugins available, and you'll still be able to access plugins using navigator object.

ngCordova Docs: http://ngcordova.com/docs/

**Since Ionic Framework makes use of ngCordova, plugins are accessible using either ngCordova wrappers like `$cordovaCamera` or navigator object `navigator.camera`.**